# Не могу сделать задачу

Tags: java, массивы

Не могу понять как сделать задачу с массивом в "Java", c чего начать?
Записался на курсы по "Java", дали задачу, битый день сижу не понимаю как ее сделать((( подскажите пожалуйста. 
Заранее благодарен за объяснение.

Сама задача:

> ```
> Input: array with size = 10 can be of one of two data types: int and double. Calculate:
>
> sum 
>
> min/max
>
> max positive
>
> multiplication  
>
> modulus of first and last element
>
> second largest element
>
> As a result you should have methods with following names :
>
> sum(int array[]), sum(double[])
>
> min(int array[]), min(double[])
>
> max(int array[]), max(double[])
>
> maxPositive(int array[]), maxPositive(double array[]),
>
> multiplication  (int array[]), multiplication (double[])
>
> modulus(int array[]), modulus(double[])
>
> secondLargest(int array[]), secondLargest(double[])
> ```

Comment: Задачу здесь за вас не решат, лучше скажите, что именно вам непонятно.

Comment: С чего начать, я не понимаю. Может какой туториал по масивам посоветуете прочитать.  
Вот к примеру, за день смог решить одну задачу ( на суму) 
`public static void main(String[] args) {
        int myArray[] = {56,53,73,123,23,56,12,465,100,303};
        int sum=0;
        for(int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
            sum=sum+myArray[i];
        }
        System.out.println(sum);`

Comment: Начните с создания предложенных в задании методов. В качестве аргументов они принимают массивы, а внутри реализуйте логику

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код суммирования всех элементов массива:

```
int [] array = {1,1,3};
int sum = 0;
for(int number : array)
    sum += number;
System.out.println(sum);
```

Код вычисления наибольшего и наименьшего числа в массиве:

```
int [] array = {1,-22,2,5,7,100};
int min = Arrays.stream(array).min().getAsInt();
int max = Arrays.stream(array).max().getAsInt();
System.out.println("Min: " + min);
System.out.println("Max: " + max);
```

Код вычисления максимального числа, которое выше 0:

```
int [] array = {1,-2,5,110,13};
int max = 0;
for(int number : array)
    if(number>0 && max<number)
        max = number;
System.out.println(max);
```

Код умножения каждого элемента массива:

```
int [] array = {1,2,3,11};
int product = 1;
for(int number : array)
    product *= number;
System.out.println("Multiplication: " + product);
```

Модуль первого и последнего элементов в массиве:

```
int [] array = {1,5,2,56};
int first = array[0];
int last = array[array.length - 1];
System.out.println("First: " + Math.abs(first));
System.out.println("Last: " + Math.abs(last));
```

Второе максимальное число в массиве:

```
int [] array = {1,5,15,61,62};
int largest = array[0];
int secondLargest = array[0];
for (int number : array)
    if (number > largest) {
        secondLargest = largest;
        largest = number;
    } else if (number > secondLargest)
        secondLargest = number;
System.out.println("Second largest: " + secondLargest);
```

Вот и всё, вам осталось только оформить в нужную архитектуру.